# What is the best way to compute a bar graph for data over varied time periods

Tags: sql, r, graph

So, I have some SQL queries to track performance measurements at work. I can't share those as my query on here for obvious reasons. However, what I'm trying to do is create a visualization based on my queries to create a bar graph that will compare data from this week, last week, and my average for the year.

Let's pretend is quarterback completion percentage, yards, touchdowns, and interceptions. I have a query that can pull them all up. What I want to be able to do is generate this query so that it pulls his stats from this week, his last time on the field, and his average for the season. And then, I want them to be in bar graphs to help visualize performance.

This is my first time taking on a larger R/SQL combined project, so I'm wondering if someone can sort of walk me through the best steps to figure it out. Any help would be massive. I know how to do basic plots and stuff, but not being able to compare them directly.

Comment: Hi petplant, please provide more details (e.g., some sample data) and what problems you are experiencing. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1) about making a reprex in R.

Comment: Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not a tutorial site. We answer specific working code that faces errors or undesired results. Try reading more from books/online/videos and then make an attempt. Come back with any specific issues with reproducible code and data sample. R has many solid libraries for DB connections and many barplot solutions.